# How is it possible to use TRIAC dimming with an 110v input LED T-8 Tube light?

Tags: led, triac, dimming

I have seen T8 or T10 Led Tubes made for entertainment lighting that can plug into a Triac dimmer and be dimmed down to approx 10% with no flicker and no color shift.  Attached is a picture of the driver I removed from the housing.

Comment: Some LED lamps are designed to be 'dimmable', some are not.

Answer (score 1):

Some explanations.

[Efficient dimming for LED lighting](http://www.electronicproducts.com/Power_Products/Power_Management/Efficient_dimming_for_LED_lighting.aspx)

[Leading-Edge vs. Trailing-Edge Dimmers](http://www.ledjournal.com/main/blogs/leading-edge-vs-trailing-edge-dimmers/)